# Prevent user to delete Firefox extension

Tags: firefox-extensions

Is it possible to prevent non-root user to delete Firefox extension?

I need to prevent from deleting Firefox plugin Block Site.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Firefox extensions systemwide by copying them to `/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/`, the ubufox extension (installable from the repositories) works that way.

An extension installed that way will be automatically loaded by every Firefox running on the system and cannot be deleted without root rights. Unfortunately, there's no way to prevent the user from simply disabling it in Firefox' addon manager.